# Visual Studio Template for UWP, XAML, DirectX and WinRT

Tags: templates, uwp, directx, winrt-xaml, c++-winrt

For a project I'm thinking of I'd like to use a combination of the following technologies.

- UWP as I'm planning to target both Desktop and XBox.
- DirectX Direct 3D 11 for animation.
- XAML as I'd rather not try to rewrite text boxes, buttons etc. Also using a SwapChainPanel.
- WinRT as there are some other C++ libraries beyond DirectX that I want to use. And C++/CX has apparently been retired hurt.

There are a number of templates but none that combine all 4 technologies. I am aware of this project [direct3d12_cppwinrt_xaml_cube](https://bitbucket.org/Izhido/direct3d12_cppwinrt_xaml_cube/src/master/Direct3D12_CppWinRT_XAML_Cube/) but it doesn't quite fit the bill.

If anyone is aware of other templates and/or projects that I can use please provide links to the relevant websites.

Or how I can adapt a project generated by one of these templates.

- Direct3D UWP Game(C++/WinRT) and add XAML
- DirectX 11 and XAML App (Universal Windows - C++/CX) convert to C++/WinRT

Comment: UWP is the right platform if you need to target Desktop and XBox. The *DirectX 11 and XAML App (Universal Windows - C++/CX)* looks like the most appropriate project template as well. There's documentation on [porting in one pass](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/move-to-winrt-from-cx#porting-in-one-pass). This involves creating a C++/CX scratch project that's to be manually transliterated into a C++/WinRT project. I *guess* you would need the *Core App (C++/WinRT)* template from the C++/WinRT NuGet package, though *Blank App* might be fine, too.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you are using a 3rd party C++ library that library needs to be compatible with the UWP.

Comment: I agree with @IInspectable, currently, The DirectX 11 and XAML App (Universal Windows - C++/CX) should be the most appropriate project template.